# Group theory and sudoku

Tags: group-theory, sudoku

I am given two Sudoku $S_1$ and $S_2$ and I have two check whether $S_1$ can be turned into $S_2$ with the symetry operators.

The two Sudoko are in a "legal" state. So a given cell (numbers $1...9$) can only occur once in a row, column and 3x3 block)

1. Value permutations: Let $v_1.....v_n \in  \{1...9 \} $ be the values of $S_1$
   $\pi$ be any bijective map $\pi:  V \rightarrow V $  where  $V=\{v_1 ...v_n\}$

A value permutation is the new Sudoko obtained by setting $v_i$ =$\pi(v_i)$

2. Permute the three stacks
3. Permute the three bands;
4. Permute the three columns within a stack
5. Permute the three rows within a band
6. Any reflection or rotation.

Essentially, I have to check if $S_2$ can be  turned into $S_1$ given these operations

The BruteForce-Way of doing this would be to generate all the symetries of $S_1$ and see if $S_2$ belongs to that set. What would be a more efficient way of checking this ?

Would appreciate any ideas/hints

Comment: Do you mean that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are in their fully solved states?

Comment: @N8tron They can be fully sollved but I mean that they are in a "legal" state. They could be empty but all cells have to be legal according to the rules of Sudoko

Comment: I think N8tron's question is whether they are in a state where they can be solved in a unique manner.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That doesn't have to be the case. Basically, I am simply asking how to determine if $S_1$ can be turned into $S_2$ given the operators above

Comment: How would the above operations maintain symmetry? In some states it would have to be the case that some permutations are illegal. Are you aware of this? For instance, if column $c_1$ contained all the numbers 1 through 9, and row $r_1$ contained the number 9 in a column other than 1, then the permutations having the number 9 in $r_1, c_1$ would be illegal.

Comment: @Aalok How would you achieve that permutation with the operations given?

Comment: @Aalok Wow, I think I accidentally deleted ur suggestion....

Comment: @XPenguen you certainly did. I am not going to type it up again

Comment: @SantanaAfton operation 1 is literally that, unless I have misinterpreted it.

Comment: @Aalok And to your other comment. Any permutation on the values of a Sudoku leaves it in a legal state

Comment: @XPenguen how would you permute this in some way?
First three rows of $col_1$
4
3
1
---
Second three rows.
2
8
9
---
Third three rows.
5
7
6

Comment: @Aalok I believe you apply a permutation of $\{1,2,\dots,9\}$ to the entire board, not to a row or column. You can get a $9$ where you want, but it would not conflict with the old $9$ since it too would have changed by your permutation.

Comment: Take a blank board then. Every possible sudoku puzzle is a possible solution. What would we mean by symmetries of it?

Comment: I see where I was confused

Comment: I think if you want to allow boards with blank positions with a non-unique solution sets you'd also need to consider all permutations of blanks.

Comment: The symetry group of the "blank"-state would only contain the blank-state. I don't see a problem with that one

Comment: A symmetry set of a board must contain boards with exactly the same number of digits as the `original' board
@N8tron

Comment: The "straight-forward" ( for me) way would be to generate all the symetry groups of $S_1$ and check whether $S_2$ belongs to the set. That's very wastefull and I look for anything better than that

Comment: I mean that the blank states will have constraints that also need to be met to have a valid solution. You'd have to consider all of the possibilities at once when permuting rows or columns or even 1,..,9

Comment: What you need is to solve the Sudoku and then make a permutation with restrictions. At a university in Scotland there is a specialist in sudoku research (I do not remember the name of either the university or the researcher, whom I wrote once) who might be interested in your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider, first, full sudoku grids $S_1$ and $S_2$.
Call  $\mathbf G$ the group of symmetry operators.
$\mathbf G$  has $9!\,2\cdot 6^8 =9!\;  3,359,232$ elements.
 $S_1$ and $S_2$ are equivalent $(\sim)$ if it exists a transformation $f \in \mathbf G\ $ such that $S_2 =f(S_1)$
The best way to check if $S_1\sim  S_2$ is to use a canonalization form.
A canonalization is a rule defining how to choose one and only one element in an equivalence class.
For instance, one can pick the minlex element :
If $S_1=\{a_1 ,...,a_{81}\}$, the minlex equivalent is the one such that the string $\{a'_1 ,...,a'_{81}\}$ is minimum.
Then, for any $S_2 \sim  S_1$, its minlex form will be $\{a'_1 ,...,a'_{81}\}$ too. Reciprocally, if two grids don't have the same minlex form, they are not equivalent.

The advantage of minlex form is that it can be used for any subgrids (i.e. puzzles) - just replace blank by zero -, or for patterns (0 or 1)
Two very efficient programs are used by [the sudoku community](http://forum.enjoysudoku.com/) :

1. **sudoku** by Glenn Fowler (gsf)
2. **gridchecker** by Mladen Dobrichev (dobrichev)

They are very [fast](http://forum.enjoysudoku.com/minlex-form-min-and-max-lists-chaining-t30325.html), 50,000 grids/second (?), but I am not able to give full details of their algorithms.

To uderstand how a canonalization works, you may have a look at this [post.](http://sudopedia.enjoysudoku.com/Canonical_Form.html)
It's a different canonalization form requiring only 648 transformed grids to check.
It works for full grids and for valid puzzles by solving the puzzles before.